# Invalid content-type in AWS Logs when testing file upload in JMETER

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

As the title says, I am trying to test an API file upload in JMeter. JMeter returns successful responses however in the Cloudwatch Logs in AWS the API appears once and any subsequent tests causes it not to show up in the log. Upon checking the first one that appears, it gives me an error of "Invalid Content-Type: multipart/form-data". How do I fix this?

P.S. I have tried putting it as a header in JMeter and I have also tried checking the box that says "Use multipart/form-data"

Here is the File Upload in JMeter:
[image]

Here is the error in the log in Cloudwatch
[image]

And here is my Header Manager in JMeter:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot provide a comprehensive answer because we don't know what form of the request does you application expect.

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, it doesn't do any other response checks, if you need to get confidence whether your request was successful or not you can add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and configure it to look for the anticipated message in the response.

With regards to the [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) normally you shouldn't manually specify it, it should be sufficient to tick `Use multipart/form-data` box in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

Also be aware that you can just record the file upload event using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and it will automatically populate the fields of the HTTP Request sampler and the HTTP Header Manager, just make sure to copy the file you will be uploading to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more information if needed.